# Call helper function within parent without redefining objects from parent in the helper

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working in Excel with VBA to collect data for a table I'm building I have to go out to a TN3270 emulator to get it. In order to work with with the emulator I have to define a few objects to do the work. I also have a few helper functions that are used by multiple functions to navigate to different screens in the emulator. So far in order to use them I have had to copy the object definitions into those functions to get them to work. This works most of the time but occasionally (and in a way I cant predictably replicate) I get an error when the helper is recreating a particular object to use.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub gather_data()
    Dim TN_Emulator As Object
    Dim Workbook As Object
    Set TN_Emulator = CreateObject("TN_Emulator.Program")
    Set Workbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim string_from_excel As String

    #for loop to go through table rows
        #put value in string_from_excel
        If string_from_excel = some condition
            go_to_screen_2
            #grab and put data back in excel
        Else
            go_to_screen_3
            #grab and put data back in excel
        End If
        go_to_screen_1
    #next loop logic
End Sub

Public Sub go_to_screen_1()
    Dim TN_Emulator As Object

    #the next step occasionally throws the error
    Set TN_Emulator = CreateObject("TN_Emulator.Program") 

    #send instructions to the emulator
End Sub
```

Is there a way to import the existing objects (that get created and used without any errors) without redefining them into the helper functions to avoid this problem? I have tried searching in google but I don't think I'm using the right search terms.

Comment: `Public Sub go_to_screen_1(TN_Emulator As Object)` and then: `Call go_to_screen_1(TN_Emulator)`

Comment: So by passing the object definition in the brackets of the helper function and passing the locally assigned variable in the function call, I don't need to include the step in the helper where I set the object?

Comment: The Key words you're looking for are: "How to pass arguments to a function".  Also take a quick read of [ByRef vs ByVal](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/byref-byval.html)

Comment: @Donald.H.Hartley you need to delete both the declaring and setting instructions on the helper function or else it will be restarted.

Comment: JosephC, Damian, Thank you both. I'll self-post an answer below showing the solution along with the ByRef vs ByVal link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thanks goes to @JosephC and @Damian for posting the answer for me in the comments.

From JosephC 'The Key words you're looking for are: "How to pass arguments to a function".', and he provided the following link [ByRef vs ByVal](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/byref-byval.html) describing two different ways to pass arguments in the function call.

And from Damian the solution to my immediate concern. Instead of declaring and setting the objects that will be used in body of the helper function. Place the object names and types in the parentheses of the initial helper name, and when calling the helper from the other function also in the parentheses, shown below.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub gather_data()
    Dim TN_Emulator As Object
    Dim Workbook As Object
    Set TN_Emulator = CreateObject("TN_Emulator.Program")
    Set Workbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim string_from_excel As String

    #for loop to go through table rows
        #put value in string_from_excel
        If string_from_excel = some condition
            Call go_to_screen_2(TN_Emulator)
            #grab and put data back in excel
        Else
            Call go_to_screen_3(TN_Emulator)
            #grab and put data back in excel
        End If
        Call go_to_screen_1(TN_Emulator)
    #next loop logic
End Sub

Public Sub go_to_screen_1(TN_Emulator As Object)
   #send instructions to the emulator
End Sub
```

I believe I understood the instructions correctly, and have successfully tested this for my-self. I also passed multiple objects in the helper function definition and calls as needed for my actual application, in the same order each time Ex.

```
Sub go_to_screen_1(TN_Emulator As Object, ConnectionName As Object)
```

and

```
Call go_to_screen_1(TN_Emulator, ConnectionName)
```